# Reset arrays value inside angular.foreach loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, foreach

I have an array of empty objects like this:

```
var a = [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ];
```

And an array of properties:

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
```

I need to assign each color in "colors" to every element of "a" array with angular foreach. But the length of "a" array is greater than "colors". I want to assign the colors "by circle" So the result needs to be like this:

```
var a = [
    {color: "red"},
    {color: "green"},
    {color: "blue"},
    {color: "red"},
    {color: "green"},
    {color: "blue"},
    {color: "red"}
];

angular.forEach(a, function(elem, index) {
  if (a.length > colors.length) {
    // .......                       
  }
  elem.color = colors[index];
});
```

The question: Is there some way to reset the index of foreach to start looping the "colors" array from beginning? Thanks for help

Comment: Try this `elem.color = colors[index % colors.length];`

Comment: @Hadi Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
var a = [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ];
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

a.forEach(function(item,key){
    item.color = colors[key % colors.length];
})
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

try javascript `map` function like this

```js
var a = [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} ]; 
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

a = a.map(function(o,i){
    var color =  (colors[i]) ? colors[i] : callFunc(i);    
    o.color =color;
    
    return o;
    
    function callFunc(i){
       var diff = (i - colors.length)% (colors.length)
       return colors[diff]
    }
})

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a counter i inside the foreach. In each iteration increment i like i++ and once it reaches the length of colors array, just reset it like i=0 and the color[i] can be used to get the color name.